# Cannot create file because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-migration

I created an asp.net mvc website with a code first database. I enabled database migration through the PM Console. I uploaded the website and database on to a server for online testing. I now want to do additional testing on my desktop so I downloaded the existing databases and placed them in the **App_Data** file.

Using the PM Console, I run the `Update-Database` command and the response is as follows:

> PM> Update-Database
>
> Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL
> statements being applied to the target database. No pending explicit
> migrations. Running Seed method.

I suspect that the database's schema is recognized as unchanged.

However, when I go to debug the website using localhost, after entering in username and password, I get the following error:

> Cannot create file 'C:\Users\XXXX\OneDrive\Visual Studio
> 2017\Projects\Testing\XXXXXX\Version
> 2.4\XXXXXX\App_Data\DB_9AEA79_data.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation. CREATE
> DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check
> related errors.

I can't figure out why VS wants to re-create a database I've placed in the **App_Data** folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you’re running the app per localDb-ConnectionString?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the issue remains unresolved.

Comment: Did you try to add the file to the localDb-instance

Comment: There is another possible solution, can you add the connection-string? Maybe I can modify it, so the Database will be attached by the application.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie and this is my first post on this site, but I hope my post will help someone. I have the same message and for a long time I could not understand what is going on.

> Cannot create file '' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

I created an asp.net mvc project with an ms sql database and Entity Framework (code first). After creating the database, I immediately opened MS SQL Server Management Studio and added the database. After closing and reopening Visual Studio I always saw the same error (if I don't close VS everything works correctly).
It turned out to be caused by connection to MS SQL Server Management Studio. It's not enough to close the program, or to disable the connection.

Here's what needs to be done.
[MS SQL SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5MTd.jpg)
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

That’s because localDb uses an SqlServerExpress-Instance to use the database.
You can attach the file to the instance, but if you only copy the file it fails.

I didn’t check it and it’s old, but maybe [the Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms239722.aspx) can help you.